# error = class DBError(exceptions.Exception) (do `help('dbhash')`), what is this language construct called?

Tags: python, django

`help('dbhash')` (standard library module):

```
CLASSES
    exceptions.Exception(exceptions.BaseException)
        bsddb.db.DBError

    error = class DBError(exceptions.Exception)
     |  Method resolution order:
     |      DBError
     |      exceptions.Exception
     |      exceptions.BaseException
     |      __builtin__.object
     :
```

How is that `error = class DBError(exceptions.Exception)`language construct called? What does it do? You can see another example of this construct when you do help('django.http.HttpResponse') if you installed django.

(I am using python 2.7.2 and django 1.4)

Comment: I have looked at the `dbhash.py` script and the `django.http.__init__.py` script. I can't figure out how the script has to be written to output that construction in the help function. Can somebody code a small example class so when you do `help('samplemodule')` you see this same construction?

Answer (score 1):

It is no valid syntax. In the help, it means to denote that `error` was originally defined as `class DBError` and derived from `exceptions.Exception`.